# Combine GAM-smooths of multiple covariates in one plot in R

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I have a list of dataframes in R. Each element of the list is a dataframe with the same covariates. However, the values of the covariates differ for each dataframe as I applied a smoothing algorithm with different combinations for each of them.

I then fitted a gam for each dataframe. And what I would like to do now is to make one plot for each covariate with the smoothing lines for each dataframe

**Update**

Just to share some code and make it a little clearer:
And now I'd like to do something like a facet-plot. Where each plot contains the smooths for a covariate (x1 and x2) of the different gams. I hope this makes sense...

```
library(mgcv)

# make list of dataframes for storing data
data = vector("list", length = 3)

#  fill the list
for(i in seq_along(data)){
  data[[i]] = gamSim(n = 200, dist = "normal", scale = 2)
}

# fit the gams
gam_models = vector("list", length(data))
for(i in seq_along(data)){
  res = gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2), data = data[[i]])
  gam_models[[i]] = res
  par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  plot(res, all.terms=TRUE, main="Name of Covariate")
}
```

Comment: Can you please share reproducible code & data? I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do. `geom_smooth` allows you to use `method = "gam"` to show GAM-based fits. This is aesthetic-dependent, i.e. if you have a `colour` or `group` aesthetic `geom_smooth` will plot a smoothed curve for every subset.

Comment: yes of course! Sorry, I'll update the confusing question a little bit...

Comment: If you provide some data/code, that generates a list of a list of models similar to what you  are working with, you will have a much higher change of getting an answer.

Comment: I updated the question and hope it makes more sense now:)

Comment: Hi @Lenn, thanks for the update, this is much better. Seeing your code example I'm now wondering what exactly the issue is. You are already plotting smoothened curves (including CIs) for every covariate for every model.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers! Sorry, I think I didn't manage to really make my issue clear... 
What I would like to do is to have the smooths of various columns (variables) of different gams in one plot. Because doing so would enable me to look at how the smooths change as a function of the smoothing (which is different in each gam). So for example have a plot with a smooth for slope (smoothing-parameter = 10) and in the same plot another smooth for the variable degree (which was smoothed with smoothing-parameter = 20). Or something like this;)

Comment: @Lenn No need to apologise;-) I'm still confused though. The code example you give *does* show individual plots for every covariate in one plot (if you change `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` to `par(mfrow = c(1, 3))` you'll see all three covariates. Take a look at my answer below for a different `ggplot2`-based option. Is that perhaps what you're after?

Comment: Thanks so much:) But what I want to do is to really put the smooths for the same covariates (that were computed with different smoothing parameters) in one single figure;) Like different lines in one plot. Really sorry for not being able to describe it better...:/

Comment: @Lenn Ok I understand now. I'm afraid what you're asking involves extracting smoothened data from the `gam` fit object yourself. You can take a look at the source code for `plot.gam` to see how this is done in `mgcv`. The routines in `mgcViz` do something similar. I don't have time to look into this, but this should be fairly straightforward. Basically, I'd define a function `get_smooth_data(fit, covariate)` that returns a `data.frame` of the smooth effects based on `fit` for `covariate`; I'd then row-bind these `data.frame`s for every model, and you're ready for plotting.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for my late reply... Thank you very much also for the help! Although this sounds straightforward I think this is still a little above my level of knowledge. However, I'll try to see what I can do:) 
Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking. The sample code you provided in your most recent edit seems to do exactly what you're after.

You've mentioned facets, so perhaps you're after a `ggplot` solution? If so, here is an option using some of the plotting methods provided by the `mgcViz` package.

```r
library(mgcViz)
library(grid)
library(tidyverse)
lst <- imap(
    setNames(gam_models, paste("Model", seq_along(gam_models), "covariates")),
    function(fit, nm) {
        terms <- fit %>% pluck("terms") %>% attr("term.labels")
        map(
            c(nm, rep("", length(terms) - 1)),
            ~textGrob(.x, hjust = 1)) %>%
        append(map(
            seq_along(terms), ~
            plot(sm(fit %>% getViz(), .x)) +
            l_fitLine(colour = "black") +
            l_ciLine(colour = "black", linetype = 2) +
            l_rug(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.8)))
    }) %>%
    unlist(recursive = FALSE)

gridPrint(grobs = lst, ncol = 3, heights = rep(c(1, 3), length(gam_models)))
```

[image]

Explanation: The idea is to build a `list` of `ggplot` objects, where rows correspond to the different GAMs, and columns to the covariates. Note that this assumes that all GAMs have the same number of covariates. To adjust for more models & covariates, you'd need to change the hard-coded parameters for `ncol` and `heights` in `gridPrint`.